# PHP - Hide/Show Content based on User Level

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have login page and user page, which after user login with correct username and password, it will go to user page.
The user page consists of a table of user list and have a 'Edit User' button next to each user row. For example, in the screenshot here -->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3qxi.png

So, based on user level, if user level = User (which has ID=4), i want to hide the edit button. What I've tried so far is like this but its not working. I have imported the session code and all the queries. This code below is just some part of what I want to do.

```
include_once("session.php");
if($_SESSION['userlvl']==4){
    echo "USER";
?>

<script>
$document.(ready(function){
  $(#editbutton).hide();
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>


<a id="editbutton"><img src="Edit.png"/></a>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You should hide it using PHP and not JavaScript, otherwise you can still find it in the source code. You should also secure your edit function and the script that receives the form, as users can still send requests to that page if they know the URL and form, even if they don't have the button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution.

```js
include_once("session.php");
if ($_SESSION['userlvl'] == 4) {
  $hideme = 'display:none;'
} else {
  $hideme = '';
} ?>


< a id = "editbutton"
style = "<?php echo $hideme; ?>" > < img src = "Edit.png" / > < /a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class instead of Id

```
include_once("session.php");
if($_SESSION['userlvl']==4){
    echo "USER";
?>

<script>
$document.(ready(function){
  $(".editbutton").hide();
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>


<a class="editbutton"><img src="Edit.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by @insertusernamehere you should use PHP to control what is written to the page depending upon the user's access level - merely hiding content from view is just asking for trouble as it is trivial to find when looking in code view. Below is just an example of how you might do this.

```
<?php
    include_once("session.php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Restrict content based upon user level example</title>
        <?php
            if( isset( $_SESSION['userlvl'] ) ){

                $level=intval( $_SESSION['userlvl'] );
                /*
                    If you have javascript functions that actually submit the forms or
                    interact somehow with the data that are to be restricted to particular
                    levels of user, generate the code for that level only.
                */
                switch( $level ){
                    case 1:
                        /* Basic user */
                        echo "
                            <script id='user' type='text/javascript'>
                                function view_record(){
                                    alert('hello world');
                                }
                            </script>
                        ";
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        /* Superuser */
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        /* Manager & Admin level users ? */
                        echo "
                        <script id='admin' type='text/javascript'>
                            function delete_all_users(){

                            }
                            function drop_tables(){

                            }
                            function drop_database(){

                            }
                            function edit_record(e){
                                alert(e+' edit record') 
                            }
                            function delete_record(e){
                                alert(e+' delete record')   
                            }
                        </script>
                        ";
                    break;  
                }
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <?php
            /* Assuming you use php to generate the table: pseudo style code */
            while( $rs=$result->fetch() ){
                $editbttn='';
                $deletebttn='';

                if( in_array( $level, array( 3,4 ) ) ){
                    /* Admin & manager */
                    $editbttn="<a class='editbutton' onclick='edit_record(event)'><img src='Edit.png'/></a>";
                    $deletebttn="<a class='deletebutton' onclick='delete_record(event)'><img src='Delete.png'/></a>";
                }

                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>DATA</td>
                        <td>DATA</td>
                        <td>DATA</td>
                        <td>$editbttn</td>
                        <td>$deletebttn</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to restrict the user that only has the privilege of "User" not to be able to edit the data?

You might want to consider trying this as I think it is more straight forward and simple?

```
session_start();
 if($_SESSION['userlvl'] == 4) {
    echo "USER";
    }else{
    $userlvlpermission = '<a id="editbutton"><img src="Edit.png"></a>';
    }
 //At where you wanted to place the "editbutton"
 <?php if($userlvlpermission){echo $userlvlpermission;}?>
```

Be sure that you check the user session of the edit page as well in case they know the exact url.

AT edit page

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['userlvl'] = 4){
echo "NO PERMISSION";
echo "header('Refresh: 3;url=page.php')";
exit();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method but there was an error saying $userlvlpermission is not defined. Btw, if I check the user session of the edit page, how can I disable the form if the user level is User? Can I make the form disabled?

Comment: I suppose you have a login page. You may do a redirection to the login page or echo "no permission to edit" and exit the script, see edited code

Comment: Okay I'll try. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see why there will be an error? care to show?

Comment: I think the error occurs because of if(userlvlpermission), because after if($_SESSION['userlvl'] == 4) {, you did not set $userlvlpermission to any value. I've tried the codes suggested by Mark Vincent Manjac and it works. His method seems similar to yours.

Comment: :), no error there still, if($userlvlpermission) is to check if this variable is set then followed by {echo ...} if the variable has been set, that is why after  the if($_SESSION['user..... ), I didn't set it. anyway, the method are entirely different from Mark Vincent. Have fun coding.